# Testing with Django's TestCase and async don't work with Database

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, asynchronous

So I'm using `django_channels` to handle some WebSocket stuff and since [Django 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#testing-asynchronous-code) you can create `unittest-like` tests for testing `async` and decided to go with that.

It happens to be that for some reason when accessing the `Consumer` can't reach the data.

I'm using `model_bakery` (but also tried with plain Django ORM) and have a very simple test.

```py
class TestChatConsumer(TestCase):
    url = '/ws/chat/'

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = baker.make_recipe('registration.user')
        self.chat = baker.make_recipe('chat.chat')

    async def test_setup_channel_layer_ok(self):
        consummer = WebsocketCommunicator(
            application=AuthMiddlewareStack(ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
            path=self.url,
        )
        consummer.scope['user'] = self.user
        await consummer.connect()
        await consummer.send_json_to({
            'type': 'setup_channel_layer',
            'chat': self.chat.pk,
        })
        response = await consummer.receive_json_from()

        self.assertEqual(response['type'], 'info')
        self.assertEqual(response['content']['message'], 'Chat connected!')
```

The problem is that on the test the entry is created but when accessing consumers the entry seems to be off.
Do you know if there's any desync between test database or something?

### Edit

I added a dummy function to check for tests on consumer and got this.

Test:
[image]

Consumer code:
[image]

Result on that breakpoint:
[image]

Comment: Can you add the consumer you are trying to test to your question and the result/failure you are currently getting?

Comment: I'm 100% sure the problem is not the consumer since I tried to reach data on `receive` and got an empty list. Also it will be a lot of code that will make this question harder to read.

Comment: I think the problem is that TestTransactionCase removes database (rollback) everytime it passes a test and since they are `async` databases are being removed because test isn't being awaited or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So at the end the problem was `django.test.TestCase`.
It was fixed by changing `class TestChatConsumer(TestCase):` for `class TestChatConsumer(TransactionTestCase):`

Seems like `TransactionTestCase` comes with a lot of features that `TestCase` doesn't have.

[See more...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase)

Comment: I'm using Django REST Framework `APITestCase` and had been dealing with the same issue. This led me to find `APITransactionTestCase` which fixed the problem!

Comment: Do glad to help you! Wish there was documentation this detailed